# angularjs- not able to submit data set in textboxes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a form which makes uses of google map's Places API. 
My form has following fields:
1) text box to enter name.
2) text box to fetch google address.
3) text box which saves latitude from google address.
4) text box which saves longitude from google address.

And I'm trying to pass all these values to a backend service but the values set by places api is not getting passed as a parameter to the service:

Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myMap">
  <form name="addForm" ng-submit="vm.addForm()" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" ng-model="vm.name" placeholder="Name" />
      <h2>Address</h2>
      <input type="text" id="source_point" name="source_point" ng-model="vm.source_point" placeholder="Enter address here">
      <input type="text" id="src_lat" name="src_lat" ng-model="vm.src_lat" placeholder="latitude">
      <input type="text" id="src_long" name="src_long" ng-model="vm.src_long" placeholder="longitude">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Add Data</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="source_map"></div>
```

and my Controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .factory('myService', function($http) {})
  .controller('myMap', function(myService, $http, $scope) {

    var vm = this;
    var map;
    var marker;
    var latLngC;

    var places1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('source_point'));
    google.maps.event.addListener(places1, 'place_changed', function() {
      var place1 = places1.getPlace();

      var src_addr = place1.formatted_address;
      var src_lat = place1.geometry.location.lat();
      var src_long = place1.geometry.location.lng();

      var mesg1 = "Address: " + src_addr;
      mesg1 += "\nLatitude: " + src_lat;
      mesg1 += "\nLongitude: " + src_long;

      document.getElementById('src_lat').value = src_lat;
      document.getElementById('src_long').value = src_long;
    });

    $scope.post = {};
    $scope.post.addForm = [];
    $scope.vm = {};
    $scope.index = '';
    var baseUrl = 'api/';
    // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred
    vm.addForm = function() {
      var dataPost = {
        eventName: $scope.vm.name,
        eventLocation: $scope.vm.source_point,
        eventLocLat: $scope.vm.src_lat,
        eventLocLong: $scope.vm.src_long
      };
      return $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: baseUrl + 'addFormData',
        data: dataPost,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

HERE's a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/e59vy5kL/)

What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setter to input for longitude and latitude is wrong:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.vm.src_lat = src_lat;
    $scope.vm.src_long = src_long;
  });
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('src_lat').value = src_lat;
  document.getElementById('src_long').value = src_long;
```

Put values into scope and angular will makes the rest :)